# cumulative distribution function of mixed type

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, piecewise-continuity

It's a general question, how do we spot a cumulative distribution function is of mixed type, that is has characteristics of both mixed and continuous type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A cdf of a purely discrete distribution is a step function (i.e. piecewise constant) with jumps at places of discrete probability weights.
- A cdf of a continuous distribution is continuous.
- A cdf of a mixed distribution is not continuous everywhere and also is not a step function (e.g. piecewise linear)